# Как передать управление из одного класса в другой c помощью goto

Tags: c#

Как передать управление из одного класса в другой. Сделал так как написано ниже в коде, но не работает. Выдает ошибку - Ошибка  5   В области действия оператора goto отсутствует метка "Link"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IView, IModelObserver
{
  private void LoadImage(bool rpt)
    {

        // директория, которая будет выбрана как начальная в окне для выбора файла 
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:";

        // если будем выбирать jpg файлы 

        // устанавливаем формат файлов для загрузки - RPT 
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "file (RPT) files (*.rpt)|*.rpt|file (RPT2) files (*.rpt2)|*.rpt2|All files (*.*)|*.*";


        // если открытие окна выбора файла завершилось выбором файла и нажатием кнопки ОК 
        this.ResumeLayout();
        col++;

    }

    // обработка кнопки меню "открыть" 
    public void открытьФайлToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            LoadImage(true);
            if (col > 1)
            {
                goto Link;
            }
            //LoadImage(false);
            // выход, если была нажата кнопка Отмена и прочие (кроме ОК)
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            {
                // всё. имя файла теперь хранится в openFileDialog1.FileName
                MessageBox.Show("Выбран файл: " + openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
            int rpt = 0;
            FileName.PathFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string format = null;
            format = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (format == ".rpt")
                rpt = 1;
            else
                rpt = 2;
            controller.getFile(FileName.PathFile, rpt);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //AllocConsole();
        Link:
        Model model1 = new Model();

        Form1 view1 = new Form1();

        Controller cnt1 = new Controller(view1, model1);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        Application.Run(view1);

    }
}
```

Comment: [goto: label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34124/discussion-between-grundy-and-svd102).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34172/discussion-on-question-by-svd102--------).

Answer (score 4):

`goto` работает только в рамках одного метода. Точкой входа в метод является его вызов, провалиться в середину метода из другого невозможно

немного об операторе [goto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Comment: Для C# правила ещё строже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, эм? тут же почти как в справке из MSDN

Comment: @Grundy, запрет на переход во вложенный блок. http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6756794#p6756794 - второй пункт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что-то мне тот пример с `if(false)` не нравится :)

Comment: @Grundy, зря :) Одно из наиболее удобных его использований.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не :-) я имел ввиду, что может компилятор и т.д. убирал этот блок и поэтому и гото не работал. но да, сейчас проверил - `if(true)` тож не работает :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, ну пример со вложенным блоком можно отнести смело к другому методу, ибо так оно и работает по своей сути

Comment: @Grundy, C# требует переход в тот же блок, или в блок, содержащий его. Переход внутрь другого блока запрещён. Хотя в других языках подобного ограничения нет.

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Тут вместо `goto` сработает

```
Program.Main();
return;
```

но всё равно, скорее всего тут что-то не то.

Comment: наверное стоило сказать, что этот код должен быть **вместо** _goto_. А то мне с первого взгляда не совсем очевидно это показалось